# Supporting 2D rendering in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, 2d, directx-11, native-code

How can i **render text**, paths, squares-ovals-other-2d-geometry **into memory** (bitmap, byte*) in **Windows Phone 8** in **C++**. This bitmap subsequently will be sent to DX3D11. In other words - an analogue of GDI required.

UPD2: [No app-store for d2d](http://kennykerr.ca/2012/12/01/windows-phone-and-direct2d/).

UPD3: Possible solution: [DirectXTK](http://directxtk.codeplex.com/) contains SpriteFont for "bitmap based text rendering".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use C++, you can try using a WriteableBitmap and modifying individual pixels.

See: [WriteableBitmap class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1)

In order to draw all the shapes you want, you can borrow methods from the WriteableBitmapEx project.  It is all written in C#, but you can probably modify it to draw all the shapes you want in C++.

These are the [Shape Extensions](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/Source/WriteableBitmapEx/WriteableBitmapShapeExtensions.cs)